# Is there any way to get related posts API in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I need to create an API that will render a related post by category filter. I have written the code in my functions.php file but I did not get how can I pass a post id to the arguments?

```
function related_posts_endpoint( $request_data ) {
    $uposts = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'category__in'   => wp_get_post_categories(183),
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post__not_in'   => array(183),
    ) );
    return  $uposts;
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'sections/v1', '/post/related/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'related_posts_endpoint'
    ) );
} );
```

I need to pass the id from my current API call. So, I need to pass that id to the related API arguments that I have currently passed as static (180)

Image of Current post API from which I need to render a related API
[image: Current post API from which I need to render a related API]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can get the post id like normal get request. `?key=value` and use its ad `$request['key']` so Your code should be like this.

```
function related_posts_endpoint( $request_data ) {
    $uposts = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'category__in'   => wp_get_post_categories(183),
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post__not_in'   => array($request_data['post_id']),//your requested post id 
    )
    );
    return  $uposts;
 }
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'sections/v1', '/post/related/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'related_posts_endpoint'
    ));
});
```

Now your api url should be like this `/post/related?post_id=183`
try this then let me know the result.

Answer (score 3):

You can add to your rest route a parameter called `post_id`, and then access the id from the `request_data` array.

```
function related_posts_endpoint( $request_data ) {

    $post_id = $request_data['post_id'];

    $uposts = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'category__in'   => wp_get_post_categories($post_id),
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post__not_in'   => array($post_id),
        )
    );

    return  $uposts;
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {

    register_rest_route( 'sections/v1', '/post/related/(?P<post_id>[\d]+)', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'related_posts_endpoint'
    ));

});
```

You can add the id to the end of your URL call `/post/related/183`.